# How to install intellij-bootstrap3 on pycharm

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, pycharm

I am new to Pycharm and I would like to know if someone know how to install intellij-bootstrap3.

The source code is located here: https://github.com/bodiam/intellij-bootstrap3

It's not obvious to me how to install it. Can someone please enlighten me?

Answer (score 0):

Just tested and it works just fine as the developer describes in project github page. All done inside Pycharm follow the steps.

```
To install the plugin open your editor (IntelliJ) and hit:

1) File > Settings > Plugins and click on the Browse repositories button.

2) Look for Bootstrap 3 the right click and select Download plugin.

3) Finally hit the Apply button, agree to restart your IDE and you're all done!
```